# For which fields is the inverse Galois problem known?

Tags: galois-theory, nt.number-theory

The inverse Galois problem is known for (or in Jarden's and Fried's terminology, the following fields are universally admissible) function fields over henselian fields (like $\mathbb{Q}_p(x)$); function fields over large fields (like $\mathbb{C}(x)$); and large Hilbertian fields (conjecturally $\mathbb{Q}^{ab}$, although I'm not certain that any field is known to be in this category).

### Clarification:

A large field $K$ (a.k.a. an ample field) is a field such that if $V$ is a variety of dimension $\geq 1$ over $K$ with at least one smooth $K$-rational point, then it has infinitely many smooth $K$-rational points. For example any algebraically closed field is large.

A Hilbertian field is more difficult to explain, but it suffices to say that any number field and any function field (over any field) is Hilbertian.

### My question is:

Is there a proof (not a conjecture) that there exists a field $K$ which is neither a function field over a henselian field, nor a function field over a large field, nor a large Hilbertian field, such that the inverse Galois problem is true over that field? (i.e. that every finite group is realizable as a Galois group over that field)

Comment: You wrote:  "A large field K  (a.k.a. an ample field) is a field such that if V  is a variety over K  with at least one K -rational point, then it has infinitely many K -rational points. For example any algebraically closed field is large."   I trust this is missing some condition on V.  Did you mean to assume that it's positive-dimensional?

Comment: I fixed it in the body.

Comment: The inverse Galois problem is also known to be true for function fields over fields that contain a large field.

Comment: Also, I am a bit surprised by the examples you give at the beginning since henselian fields are large. 

Comment: I suppose you're right about the henselian fields.. About if I recall correctly, field that contain large fields are large.

Comment: I am no specialist, but I would be very surprised if a field like $k(T)$ could ever be large.

Comment: A hilbertian field is a field k such that for every irreducible polynomial f(x,y) with coefficients in k that is separable in y there exists a in k such that f(a,y) is irreducible over k. 

Answer (score 8):

You should find what you want in the following article by Jochen Koenigsmann: The regular inverse Galois problem over non-large fields. J. Europ. Math. Soc., 6(4):425–434, 2004.